# VBA how to ask a user to input and change the background color?

Tags: vba

Suppose there are order id in column A,
i want to create a button ask the user to enter a order id and then the vba program will find the input id from column A and change the background color to green.

here is the code I tried

```
Sub finish()
    Dim inputID As String
    inputID = InputBox("Enter order ID")
    Dim orderID As Range
    Set orderID = Range("A:A").Find(what:=inputID.Value, LookIn:=xlValue, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not orderID Is Nothing Then
        orderID.Interior.Color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

There is an error occur in line 5 how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi if I've solved your problem could you tick my answer as correct. It just helps sort of close the question if there's an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's it back to you:

```
Sub finish()
Dim inputID As String
 inputID = InputBox("Enter order ID")
  Dim orderID As Range
 Set orderID = Range("A:A").Find(what:=inputID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
 If Not orderID Is Nothing Then
    orderID.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 End If
    
End Sub
```

What you had incorrect:

-The `what` in `Find` should just be `inputID` not `inputID.value`.

-With the `LookIn` you missed the `s` on `xlValues`

-You were missing the `End If`.